# Aligning of two images on the turtle screen in Python

Tags: python, alignment, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am drawing a dot and then a block using the turtle module. However, the dot and the block are not 100% aligned, the block is displayed slightly above the dot's level. I am trying to get it to be one the same level.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tim = Turtle()

def encoding_dot():
    tim.hideturtle()
    tim.dot(10)  # Draw dot without pendown()
    tim.penup()

def draw_block():
    brick_length = 30
    brick_width = 15
    tim.fillcolor('black')
    tim.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        tim.forward(brick_length)
        tim.left(90)
        tim.forward(brick_width)
        tim.left(90)

    tim.end_fill()
    tim.penup()

encoding_dot()
tim.forward(15)
draw_block()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[dot and block images on turtle screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tLTy.png)

Comment: I suggest commenting out `#tim.hideturtle()`. Seeing the turtle makes it easier to debug. If you do that, you'll see that the block is drawn from the bottom-left corner. So you can position the block `width / 2` down from its current location by moving the turtle downward by that amount, then facing the turtle back in the original direction you want to draw the block. Give it a try, and please let me know how it goes. BTW, `width` is being used as height here. I'd use `width` for x-axis and `height` for y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

As big a fan as I am of `dot`, which seems to draw nicer circles, I would suggest that you instead use a filled `circle` as it behaves more like the rectangle you're drawing:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BRICK_LENGTH = 30
BRICK_HEIGHT = 15

def draw_encoding_dot():
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(BRICK_HEIGHT/2)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def draw_block():
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(BRICK_LENGTH)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(BRICK_HEIGHT)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

draw_encoding_dot()
turtle.forward(15)
draw_block()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Dots are drawn from their center given a diameter whereas circles are drawn from their edge given a radius.

[image]

As always, @ggorlen's advice is quite sound (+1).

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Circle height aligns perfectly with block height. I was sctually exploring building a morse codr convrrter through uding a GUI interfacr, but its no mean feat.